# Scraping w/ Selenium returns "none:

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape company profile pages from capterra using selenium. Capterra loads profile pages in batches of 25. My code is able to get the first 5, but then returns "none" for the other 20 on the page.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.capterra.com/waste-management-software/")

page = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# Hits "Show More" button
driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Show More')]").click()
# Grabs Company portfolio page links
plinks = [div.a for div in page.findAll("div", attrs={"class" : "nb-mb-0"})]

for link in plinks:
    print(link)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
<a class="nb-thumbnail nb-relative nb-thumbnail-medium nb-thumbnail-interactive" href="/p/81310/AMCS/"><img alt="" class="nb-max-h-full" loading="lazy" src="https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/946474e4-bd54-451d-bbaf-9c5602b2f399.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;w=180&amp;h=180"/></a>
<a class="nb-thumbnail nb-relative nb-thumbnail-medium nb-thumbnail-interactive" href="/p/103755/HazMat-T-T/"><img alt="" class="nb-max-h-full" loading="lazy" src="https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/838db9d8-c251-4d78-aa69-a9cd745ef6b9.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;w=180&amp;h=180"/></a>
<a class="nb-thumbnail nb-relative nb-thumbnail-medium nb-thumbnail-interactive" href="/p/79230/WAM-Hauler-Easy-Bill-Route/"><img alt="" class="nb-max-h-full" loading="lazy" src="https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/0820f6ea-9d9d-4062-987b-a3fcf25f2813.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;w=180&amp;h=180"/></a>
<a class="nb-thumbnail nb-relative nb-thumbnail-medium nb-thumbnail-interactive" href="/p/152697/Waste-Management-Software/"><img alt="" class="nb-max-h-full" loading="lazy" src="https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/64597b5d-84e5-464c-ae60-84a1c5ad4976.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;w=180&amp;h=180"/></a>
<a class="nb-thumbnail nb-relative nb-thumbnail-medium nb-thumbnail-interactive" href="/p/177472/Via-Analytics/"><img alt="" class="nb-max-h-full" loading="lazy" src="https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/c20bf8d6-88cc-49d5-8424-b724ba734d4a.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;w=180&amp;h=180"/></a>
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

What I really need from the output is the hrefs that contain "/p/". Hit the "Show More" button on the page, and then collect the next 25 links, hit button, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Did me answer resolve you problem? Who can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: This is amazing! How would I now go to each of those 125 URLS (Example: URL: https://www.capterra.com/p/86768/FAMA/) and get the Company name, rating, location, url, and the list of features? This is super cool stuff!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need selenium. Here you have an **API** and you can scrape directly API with **one request** it returns you **125 objects** you need.

```py
import json
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {'htmlName': 'waste-management-software', 'countryCode': 'ES'}
base_url = "https://www.capterra.com/p/"
response = requests.get('https://www.capterra.com/directoryPage/rest/v1/category', params=params, headers=headers)
json = json.loads(response.content)

products = json["pageData"]["categoryData"]["products"]
print("Total elements: " + str(len(products)))
for product in products:
    print("Name: " + product["product_name"])
    print("URL: " + base_url + str(product["product_id"]) + "/" + product["product_slug"] + "/")
    print("Product url: " + product["product_url"])
    print("Image: " + product["logo_filepath"])
    print("Rating: " + str(product["rating"]))
    print()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Total elements: 125
Name: FAMA
URL: https://www.capterra.com/p/86768/FAMA/
Product url: https://info.gartnerdigitalmarkets.com/fama-es-gdm-lp
Image: https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/7a7a8467-9a2c-40d9-8488-7d6c3c0dec52.jpeg
Rating: 3.6

Name: Quentic
URL: https://www.capterra.com/p/127188/Quentic/
Product url: https://go.quentic.com/hazardous-materials-management-software
Image: https://gdm-catalog-fmapi-prod.imgix.net/ProductLogo/ba5e26a7-375d-4423-a1f2-68a27d5318c5.png
Rating: 4.8
```

Comment: Where did you find the API and where can I learn more?

Comment: In Chrome dev tools -> Network see https://medium.com/@ConnorFinnegan/how-to-effectively-inspect-network-activity-in-chrome-dev-tools-fd18592a735a#:~:text=To%20access%20this%20feature%20in,down%20menu%20at%20the%20top.

Comment: Is there a way to add a random user agent per request and/or to have a list of proxies?

Comment: Google, find some user-agent, do one list, take random one from this list....